# How do I access TypeScript definitions in ASP.NET 5 with the NuGet package manager?

Tags: asp.net, typescript, nuget-package

I am having trouble understanding how I can access the TypeScript definition files which I installed with the NuGet package manager. I installed the TypeScript definition files for Angular with the following command:

> ```
> Install-Package angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
> ```

And it shows up in the project.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped": "3.2.5"
},
```

And a reference has been placed under 'References', linking to:

> C:\Users\.k\packages\angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped\3.2.5

I am able to reference to this by using the absolute path, but this won't work:

```
/// <reference path="C:\Users\<user>\.k\packages\angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped\3.2.5\Content\Scripts\typings\angularjs\angular.d.ts" />
```

Angular depends on jQuery, which it will look for in:

> 'C:/Users//.k/packages/angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/3.2.5/Content/Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts'

So my question is: how can I reference to TypeScript definition files installed as a NuGet package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently `angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped` nuget package supports only ASP.NET 4 folders structure. It puts files in your `~\Scripts\typings\angularjs\`, (see [nuget-automation source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/NugetAutomation/blob/master/CreatePackages.ps1#L163)) folder you can reference it from there like this:

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
```

In order to use typings in ASP.NET 5 you have to just copy `*.d.ts` files from  `\packages\angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped\[VERSION]` to any folder accessible from your project and change reference path accordingly.

P.S. Feel free to create new issue in [NugetAutomation](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/NugetAutomation/issues) on GitHub.

Comment: It doesn't add any TypeScript files to my /Scripts folder. This is the way it used to work, but my question is specifically about ASP.NET 5. Or should it also add the files and am I missing something?

Comment: Happens :). Thank you for your update. I think I will go with tsd from NPM until this is supported.

Comment: Could one use a task runner like gulp to copy the files to `wwwroot`?

Comment: For anyone wondering exactly where those packages are stored, type this into your explorer's address bar: `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`