# Asp.net 5 cant find jquery.d.ts after installing nuget package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying to get typescript intellisense support for jquery for an asp.net 5 project in visual studio 2015.

I use PM> Install-Package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

This appears to complete successfully.  If I look under project references for DNX 4.5.1 and Core 5.0 I can see the packages listed:
[image: Project References as proof of install]

However I cannot find the 'jquery.d.ts' anywhere in my solution.

I am not getting any intellisense in my typescript files.

What do I need to do to get intellisense working?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801548/how-do-i-access-typescript-definitions-in-asp-net-5-with-the-nuget-package-manag

Comment: This should be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your **jquery.TypeScript.DefnitelyTyped** version.

Go to `Tools=>NuGet Packet manager=> Packet Manager Console` 
and then type these commands there

> Get-Package -updates
>
> Update-Package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

Comment: Sure!  I'm new to stack overflow...I'll definitely lookout for the format